# How do I make a table of indexes

Tags: java, list, printing

In my code I have a couple of print statements that I want to arrange into a table. The print statements vary in length depending on the numbers inputted by the user. I have the code down to where it only needs to arrange itself correctly into the table.

Here is the bit of code that isn't working correctly:

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class DataAnalyze {

public static void main(String[] args) {
    int  i = 0,  SS = 0, Count = 0, ave1 = 0,ave2=0,ave3=0,ave4=0;  
    int sum1 = 0, sum2 = 0, sum3 = 0, sum4 = 0;
    int max = 0, max1 = 0, max2 = 0, max3 = 0, max4 = 0;
    int min = 0, min1=0,min2=0,min3=0,min4=0;
    int [] arr1;
    int [] arr2;
    int [] arr3;
    int [] arr4;



    // Declaring variables
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    // Creating scanner
    System.out.print("Please enter the sample size: ");
    SS = input.nextInt();
    arr1 = new int [SS];
    arr2 = new int [SS];
    arr3 = new int [SS];
    arr4 = new int [SS];
    // Finding sample size
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial: ");


    for (i = 0; i < SS; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter sample " + Count + ": ");
        arr1[i] = input.nextInt();
        Count++;
        sum1 += arr1[i];
    }
    ave1 = sum1/Count;
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial: " );
    int Count1 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SS; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter sample " + Count1 + ": ");
        arr2[i] = input.nextInt();
        Count1++;
        sum2 += arr2[i];
    }
    ave2 = sum2/Count1;
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial: ");
    int Count11 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SS; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter sample " + Count11 + ": ");
        arr3[i] = input.nextInt();
        Count11++;
        sum3 += arr3[i];
    }
    ave3 = sum3/Count11;
    System.out.println("Enter numbers for Trial: ");
    int Count111 = 0;
    for (i = 0; i < SS; i++) {

        System.out.print("Enter sample " + Count111 + ": ");
        arr4[i] = input.nextInt();
        Count111++;
        // I couldn't get Count to reset to 0 so I made them all different variables to keep everything accurate.
        sum4 += arr4[i];
    }
    ave4 = sum4/Count111;
    System.out.println("\tSample #\tTrial 1\tTrial 2\tTrial 3\tTrial 4");
    for ( i = arr1.length ; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println("\t"+(arr1.length-i) +  " \t\t"+ arr1[arr1.length-i] );

    }
    for ( i = arr2.length; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(  "\t\t"+  " \t\t"+ arr2[arr2.length-i]);

    }
    for ( i = arr3.length; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(  "\t\t"+  " \t\t\t"+ arr3[arr3.length-i]);
    }
    for ( i = arr4.length; i > 0; i--) {
        System.out.println(  "\t\t"+  " \t\t\t\t"+ arr4[arr4.length-i]);
    }
    System.out.println("---------------------------------------------------------------------------");
    System.out.println("Average: " + "\t\t" + ave1 + "\t" + ave2 + "\t" + ave3 + "\t" +ave4);


    if (ave1>ave2&&ave1>ave3&&ave1>ave4)
        max = ave1;
    if (ave2>ave1&&ave2>ave3&&ave2>ave4)
        max = ave2;
    if (ave3>ave1&&ave3>ave2&&ave3>ave4)
        max = ave3;
    if (ave4>ave1&&ave4>ave2&&ave4>ave3)
        max = ave4;

    if (ave1<ave2&&ave1<ave3&&ave1<ave4)
        min = ave1;
    if (ave2<ave1&&ave2<ave3&&ave2<ave4)
        min = ave2;
    if (ave3<ave1&&ave3<ave2&&ave3<ave4)
        min = ave3;
    if (ave4<ave1&&ave4<ave2&&ave4<ave3)
        min = ave4;

    System.out.println("Min Average: " + min);
    System.out.println("Max Average: " + max);
    if (min == max){
        System.out.print("The trials match EXACTLY!");
    }
    else if (max < min*2) {
        System.out.print("The trials concur with each other!");
    }
    else if (max > min*2) {
        System.out.print("The trials do not concur!");
    }
}}
```

Comment: It's diagonal because every line has one more tab characters than the last. `" \t\t"`, then `" \t\t\t"`, then `" \t\t\t\t"`... Undo that- use the same number of tabs each time- and you're set. Or, you can use [`printf` with a minimum length specifier](http://sharkysoft.com/archive/printf/docs/javadocs/lava/clib/stdio/doc-files/specification.htm).

Comment: The title of this question may be misleading, and the variable names aren't helping.  Is each arri supposed to be the row i or the column i?  Since you're increasing the number of tabs, I wonder if each arr is supposed to be a column?

Comment: Please provide an example that actually compiles.

Comment: You could also use normal `System.out.print("")` if you don't want the newline appended to the end of the string.

Comment: @ZeroOne I've added the actual program to the code so it will compile

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't need four for-loops, you just print the stuff in one loop:

```
for (i = arr1.length; i > 0; i--) {
    System.out.println("\t" + (arr1.length - i) + " \t" + arr2[arr1.length - i] + " \t" + arr3[arr1.length - i] + " \t" + arr4[arr1.length - i]);
};
```

Also, once your code works perfectly, you might want to post it to https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some ideas on how to make it more readable and maintainable.

Comment: Yes! Thank you so much! I didn't know how to combine the arrays into one line but now it works!

Comment: Good to hear that helped, @Julio! :) In that case please accept my answer by clicking the check mark under the number with the arrows above and below (to the left of my answer).

Comment: Happy to help. :) And may I still emphasize that once your code works perfectly, it'd be a very good idea to post it to the Code Review site at http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ to get some insight into various best practices of Java programming.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you're asking how, given some arrays, to print them in such a way that each array becomes a column of the table.  The easiest way to do that may be to simply put them iterate through the rows of the table, and then for each row, iterate through the column values.  Here's a version that doesn't do quite enough index bounds checking.  Note that each element is printed with **print**, so that there's no newline, and after a row's elements are printed, we print the newline with **println**.

```
public class PrintTabularExample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        int[] arr1 = { 1, 2, 3 };
        int[] arr2 = { 4, 5, 6 };
        int[] arr3 = { 7, 8, 9 };

        for ( int i = 0 ; i < arr1.length; i++ ) {
            for ( int[] arr : new int[][] { arr1, arr2, arr3 } ) {
                System.out.print( "\t"+ arr[i] );   
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
1   4   7
2   5   8
3   6   9
```

Here's a version with better bounds checking, so that you can print tables of columns of different lengths:

```
public class PrintTabularExample {
    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        printTabular( new Integer[][] {
                { 1, 2 },
                { 3, 4, 5, 6 },
                { 7, 8, 9 } } );
    }

    public static <T> void printTabular( T[][] elements ) {
        // Find out how many rows to print in total.
        int maxRows = 0;
        for ( T[] arr : elements ) {
            if ( arr.length > maxRows ) {
                maxRows = arr.length;
            }
        }

        // Print the elements, tabulating for each column, but 
        // only accessing a value if the subarray has enough elements.
        for ( int i = 0; i < maxRows; i++ ) {
            for( T[] arr : elements ) {
                System.out.print("\t");
                if ( i < arr.length ) {
                    System.out.print( arr[i] );
                }
            }
            System.out.println();
        }
    }
}
```

```
1   3   7
2   4   8
    5   9
    6
```

Comment: Would it matter that the arrays aren't defined by a certain set of numbers?

Comment: @Julio I'm not sure what you mean.  The second version, which is generic, will work with an array of arrays of any type.